# How to increase number of displayed rows in a tabular form using apex 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, tabular-form

Currently my tabular form displays 10 rows at a time.  How do I increase the number of rows to be displayed, say from the current default number of 10 to something like 20?  Is there a place somewhere in the page attribute where you can set the number of rows to be displayed, as in the case of an interactive report?

Answer (score 5):

Region -> Attributes -> Layout -> **Number of Rows**

Answer (score 1):

In scripting window you will find a drop-down with row label, select it and choose the number of rows you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this problem for an 11g Oracle SQL Developer:

[More than 10 rows available. Increase rows selector to view more rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5txl.png)

Then you can directly solve this from drop down menu of rows situated beside **Autocommit** checkmark from **SQL Workshop**:

**select 1000000 to show more rows :**

[image: select 1000000 to show more rows]

Run those queries again!

**Final Result having 21 rows in result :**

[image: Final Result having 21 rows in result]

This might have solve your problem!

Comment: This question is related to **Oracle Application Express**, not SQL Developer, so - your answer might be correct, but is irrelevant in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can call function

`javascript:apex.widget.tabular.addRow();`

N number of times per click... For example,

```
Generate 2 rows, call
    javascript:apex.widget.tabular.addRow();
    javascript:apex.widget.tabular.addRow();

Generate 4 rows, call
    javascript:apex.widget.tabular.addRow();
    javascript:apex.widget.tabular.addRow();
    javascript:apex.widget.tabular.addRow();
    javascript:apex.widget.tabular.addRow();
```